# mapping c# method parameters to sql stored procedure parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i am sending parameters from c# method to sql server stored procedure like this:

```
    public void YENI_ALM_SIFARISI_AC(
        decimal TEKLIF_BEDELI2,
        string REFERANS_NO,
        string CARIKOD,
        string CARIAD,
        string ACIKLAMA,
        int SUB_ID,
        int DETAY_ID,
        string DETAY,
        decimal SUB_TEKLIF,
        decimal QIYMET,
        string OLCU_VAHIDI,
        decimal IS_HECMI
        )
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Sumqayit"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("YENI_ALM_SIFARISI_AC", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEKLIF_BEDELI2",TEKLIF_BEDELI2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REFERANS_NO",REFERANS_NO);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARIKOD",CARIKOD);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CARIAD",CARIAD);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACIKLAMA",ACIKLAMA);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUB_ID",SUB_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DETAY_ID",DETAY_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DETAY",DETAY);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUB_TEKLIF",SUB_TEKLIF);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QIYMET",QIYMET);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OLCU_VAHIDI",OLCU_VAHIDI);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS_HECMI",IS_HECMI);

            con.Open();
            int DataID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(DataID));
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

it seems that i copy and paste the same parameter names both on void parameters and sqlCommand parameters. is there any way to map these parameters so that i will not copy and paste these parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflections. Wrap all function arguments into a class and you can do something like:

```
foreach(var prop in foo.GetType().GetProperties()) {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ($"@{prop.Name}", prop.GetValue(foo, null)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void YENI_ALM_SIFARISI_AC(
        decimal TEKLIF_BEDELI2,
        string REFERANS_NO,
        string CARIKOD,
        string CARIAD,
        string ACIKLAMA,
        int SUB_ID,
        int DETAY_ID,
        string DETAY,
        decimal SUB_TEKLIF,
        decimal QIYMET,
        string OLCU_VAHIDI,
        decimal IS_HECMI
        )
    {
        var parameters = new foo();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {               
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("YENI_ALM_SIFARISI_AC", con);
            foreach (var prop in  parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{prop.Name}", prop.GetValue(parameters, null));
            }

            con.Open();
            int DataID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(DataID));
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }


    public class foo
    {
        decimal TEKLIF_BEDELI2   { get; set; }
        string REFERANS_NO       { get; set; }
        string CARIKOD           { get; set; }
        string CARIAD            { get; set; }
        string ACIKLAMA          { get; set; }
        int SUB_ID               { get; set; }
        int DETAY_ID             { get; set; }
        string DETAY             { get; set; }
        decimal SUB_TEKLIF       { get; set; }
        decimal QIYMET           { get; set; }
        string OLCU_VAHIDI       { get; set; }
        decimal IS_HECMI         { get; set; }
    }
```

i did like that. it is a webmethod in .asmx file.but still im copying and pasting the arguments twice.